# SSH/FTP connection denied after terminal automatically change ComputerName

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, mac, ftp

I was using SSH and FTP connection using terminal and ATOM respectively on my MAC. My local machine (MAC) was able to connect to the Linux PC through SSH and FTP on my home network. When I moved both machines to the office network my MAC seemed to have changed its ComputerName in terminal. Previously int terminal it was `UserName@MacbookPro ~ %` now it is `UserName@mobile44 ~ %`. However my computer name in SystemPreference>RemoteSharing is still *MacbookPro* but in SystemPreference > Network > Advance > WINS have MOBILE44 as NetBIOS name.

I remember connecting to the Linux machine through SSH on my office network at-least once using this command: `ssh -v linuxusername@linux-laptop' and for FTP I used .ftpconfig file.

Now when I try to make connection through terminal I get this and time out after a while:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.17.0.1 [172.17.0.1] port 22.
```

For FTP connection I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND aceinna-nvidia-laptop.local aceinna-nvidia-laptop.local:22
```

I would appreciate some help to get the SSH connection working again. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rishit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a DNS issue. The computer names you use end in `.local`. Although that might have worked at home, at the office there is likely a different setup and those names are probably not right. Try to connect using the IP address instead of a computer name. You can also use `ping` to make sure you can reach the other machine first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ronald. I am able make SSH connection using IP address. I cant use username@hostname to connect through SSH. I guess its working using IP address but not using hostnames. Is there a possible solution to that? Plus why would my MAC change the hostname in terminal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Macs are just like that, they do that. The name they show there can be influenced by the network you are connected with I think. If you can connect using IPs, then to make it work with names, you need to set up the names you want in a DNS service to point to the IP addresses. You would typically get your network administrator to do this. Alternatively, you can add a line to the `/etc/hosts` file but be careful, this is a system file.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for helping out.